# Sub-Query Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two tables like this

Member and their Purchases

I need the output like this

```
Member_ID | CountofProducts
```

(and the Product Value not should be 0 and Purchase Status = 1)

```
SELECT     
    MemberName,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
     FROM dbo.Purchases 
     WHERE MemberName = dbo.Members.MemberName
       AND Res_Status = 1) AS Count 
FROM   
   dbo.Members
```

I can get their total `CountofPurchased Products` from the above query but I need to avoid their `count=0` how to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  m.MemberName, 
        COUNT(p.*) Cnt 
FROM    Members m INNER JOIN 
        Purchases p     ON  m.MemberName = p.MemberName 
WHERE   p.Res_Status = 1 
GROUP BY    m.MemberName
```

There is no need for the `HAVING` clause, as the `INNER JOIN` will exclude all entries in Members that do not have Purchases.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   m.MemberName, COUNT(p.*) AS CountOfProducts
FROM     Members m
INNER    JOIN Purchases p ON m.MemberName = p.MemberName
WHERE    p.Res_Status = 1
GROUP BY m.MemberName
HAVING   COUNT(p.*) > 0
```

I think the above will somewhat do what you want.  The key is that you probably do not even need your subquery, but rather you can handle the query (possibly with greater efficiency) just using a join.